# Are there any ISS component failures that could cause irreparable harm to the station?

Tags: iss, nasa, in-space-repairs

What component, if any, would cause irreparable harm ("total") the ISS if it were to break or require replacement? If this component exists, when is it going to reach its end-of-life?

By "total", I mean that it would be cheaper to build a new space station rather than repair or replace the broken component. Also, since this  hypothetical repair might go into [Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) territory, I would consider the ISS to have been "totaled" if it's given a new name afterwards, like ISS2 instead of ISS.

Answer (score 20):

Speculative, but I'll nominate the [S0 Truss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Truss_Structure#S0_truss).

This truss segment forms the center of the ISS truss structure and also connects the truss to the chain of pressurized modules. If the S0 suffered complete structural failure, the truss could separate into two sections and the chain of pressurized modules into a third.  Since the majority of electrical power comes from, and the majority of heat rejection goes to, the truss, it would be catastrophic even if the modules remained pressurized.

The S0 is highlighted in gold here and pointed out by the red arrow. Image created by myself using [DOUG](https://software.nasa.gov/software/MSC-23586-1).

[image]

The S0 truss is fairly old; it was added to the ISS in April 2002 during shuttle mission [STS-110](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-110). I am aware of studies done back when I worked at JSC in the 2014 timeframe concerning extension of the station life to 2024, but I don't have any information about the results.

I am not advancing this as a credible failure; just what seems to me would be one of the failures with the worst impact.

Comment: what could a gyro do if it spontaneously broke into a few pieces at maximum angular velocity?

Comment: Can we really consider a whole truss structure as a single “component”?

Comment: @Michael If so, I nominate the ISS. If the ISS required replacement, it could cause us to launch a new station instead of using the ISS. The gold highlight does appear to consist of two separate sections...

Comment: @uhoh do ISS have physical gyros? Reaction wheels are another matter and probably don't rotate that fast to start with. And they probably have multiple of them in every direction.

Comment: @fraxinus https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20100021932.pdf 6600 rpm

Comment: What if one of the central modules, like Node 1 suffered a large puncture? If one of the exterior modules gets a hole in it, then it can just be sealed off but damage to Unity or Destiny would cripple ISS operations imo